# How to use same session on two laravel project?

Tags: laravel

I try to use same session on my project 1 into project 2 . when user login into first project and second project login with role access that i have setup like admin or user the second project will filter the content base on  role in project 1 .

Answer (score 0):

I think it's really an anti-pattern and bad practice in general to share cookies and sessions. Take a look at laravel passport for example. You could implement an authorization server, which controls access for the two apps, these in turn will receive tokens to verify and allow/block users.

This will scale much better and will allow for further extension in the future. But more important, this is a tested solution for these problems.